# Seg fault while using the block getter message

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to blocks. I was trying to run this piece of of code in the command line, to understand how blocks work. When i ran the code through the command line, I get a Seg fault. But when I'm using Xcode to run the same code, it compiles and runs just fine. Here's the code:-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BlockTest:NSObject
@property (copy) void (^block) (void);
-(void)run; 
@end

@implementation BlockTest
@synthesize block;
-(void)run{
   NSObject *obj= [[NSObject alloc] init];

   block = ^void (void){
   NSLog(@"my object- %@",obj);
   };

 NSLog(@"running the block...");
 block();
}
@end

int main(){
  BlockTest *test= [[BlockTest alloc] init];
  [test run];
  NSLog(@"%@",[test block]);
}
```

Here's the output when i run it in Xcode:-

2015-01-03 23:13:41.187 BlockTest[999:41316] running the block...

2015-01-03 23:13:41.189 BlockTest[999:41316] my object-

2015-01-03 23:13:41.190 BlockTest[999:41316] <**NSMallocBlock**: 0x1003096a0>

When i run it in the command line however, i get this:-

2015-01-03 23:32:50.441 BlockTest[1115:47957] running the block...

2015-01-03 23:32:50.443 BlockTest[1115:47957] my object-

Segmentation fault: 11

How come i be getting a Seg fault?? Pls assist. Thanx

Comment: when you say, "run it on the command line", what do you mean? Are you compiling it the same way in both cases?

Comment: By 'running in the command line', i mean compiling it using gcc-llvm compiler and then running the generated binary.

Comment: LLVM-GCC doesn't support ARC. Only LLVM-Clang does. Plus, LLVM-GCC is ancient; in Xcode 5 and above, it simply redirects to LLVM-Clang. Are you sure you have ARC enabled, using the `-fobjc-arc` flag or something, when you compile it on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are details missing, such as are you using MRC or ARC? So here is a guess.

When you do:

```
block = ^void...
```

you are assigning directly to the backing variable of the property, this will bypass the semantics of the `copy` attribute. If the block is not copied it will be destroyed when `run` returns, and then you'll get a memory fault.

Change to:

```
self.block = ^void...
```

so that the property setter is used and the copy done.

HTH

BTW: You don't need `@synthesize` these days, properties will be created automatically and will use a backing variable called *_property*. In general you should always set properties using *self.property* as that supports KVO and the `copy` attribute. You should also make sure you are using ARC.

**Addendum**

From the comments (on this and the main question) it appears you are compiling your code using a different compiler for running on the command line. This would appear to explain the differences.

*Without* ARC you must use `self.block = ...` as described above in order for `copy` of the property to be applied. With ARC even though the property setter itself is bypassed ARC will insert a block copy as part of the assignment.

You should compile with the current versions of Xcode/the Clang compiler in both cases. If you select the project type as "Command Line Tool" in Xcode then the binary produced is a command line binary. To locate it quickly you can right-click the binary name in Xcode and select "Show in Finder". Run that binary in the Terminal and it will work.

Comment: Note that this will only explain the crash if he is using MRC. But the first output ("in Xcode") seems to indicate ARC, since it shows NSMallocBlock, but nothing would copy the block in MRC. Maybe he is using ARC in one and MRC in the other.

Comment: @newacct - I puzzled over that as well, hence the "guess" ;-)

Comment: @rahulbsb - Well you might not be using ARC, see addendum.

Comment: @newacct This means the clang-llvm uses ARC implicitly.. Pls correct me if I'm wrong on this. Now i just tried using this- clang -framework Foundation Desktop/Source\ Code/BlockTest.m -o Desktop/Binaries/BlockTest. Then ran this BlockTest binary generated this time with clang (earlier i had used gcc) .. Again i get the Seg fault error in the last output (3rd line) as mentioned in the original post..Logically this should not be happening since clang front end is implicitly using ARC. So in the code, even though the setter method is bypassed, ARC will insert a block copy.Why the error now?

Comment: rahulbsb - (in regard to previous comment to @newacct). Xcode invokes Clang passing *many* arguments as determined from the project settings. Among them is `-fobjc-arc` if the projects ARC setting is enabled. (To see the Clang command line used by Xcode look in the build log.) When you called Clang directly you did not pass all the same arguments, and in particular no `-fobjc-arc`. Try as suggested in the Addendum, use the binary Xcode as compiled for you.

Comment: @CRD I just used the -fobjc-arc option with gcc-llvm as well as clang-llvm in the terminal for building the binary. Now it isn't giving Seg-fault.. It turns out that we can use -fobjc-arc option with gcc version of llvm as well.. I didn't know this.. Now that the ARC is in play, bypassing the setter method wouldn't matter.. I had forgotten that while using ARC, u can use the ivar variable (without declaring one) through the property name itself and then the optimization wud be done for u when u bypass the setter method in order to set up the ivar.

Comment: @CRD I know i can simply locate the binary from Xcode and then run it in the terminal.. But i wanted to know the difference and various options in the commandline.. I had put together this test code in a normal text editor just to get a better hang of things.. ARC is super cool but it just has made me take things for granted a bit..ARC spoils u in some ways while one is learning the inner workings..

Comment: @rahulbsb - Look at Xcode's build log - you can find it using View -> Navigators -> Show Log Navigator - scroll down to the compile section and expand, you'll see the clang command line in all its glory (its long).

Comment: @CRD Earlier u said that in MRC environment, unless u explicitly set an ivar (be it an objPtr or a block)  in a setter method or using self.objPtr, u won't be able to the get the object by passing a relevant getter message. That means one should receive probably a dangling pointer's value or maybe nil. So in MRC mode, i tried this by creating another property of type 'id' and did not set it using self.ptr or a setter method but by directly assigning the ivar an object. In the main function, after passing the run message (where the direct ivar assignment had been done), getter msg is used.

Comment: Unlike the block's case this time there is No error. I get the object's value. I think I'm missing something very important here. Kindly assist from MRC perspective. Has this something to do with copy attribute specifically?

Comment: @rahulbsb - while a block is an object an *optimisation* is used which allows them to be created on the local stack rather than on the heap as for other objects, and anything allocated on the stack disappears when the stack is unwound on method return etc. Under ARC this optimisation is handled like any other - it is effectively invisible to the programmer and stack blocks are copied to the heap as required to maintain their correct lifetimes. Under older compilers/MRC the optimisation is visible to the programmer and the block must be copied manually as needed - the copy attribute is one way.

Comment: @CRD saving a copy of the block literal in the heap section happens during compilation..Isn't it? In case we were manually copying it in the setter method like [block copy], would the compiler figure out that the copy needs to be maintained in the heap??

Comment: Right..Now i got it. A block literal is basically stored on the stack frame of the method in which it is defined. Its address (in the code above) is stored by the 'block' ivar. When this frame gets popped off the stack, the ivar becomes a dangling pointer. Hence the Seg fault.. In order to avoid this we needed to copy the literal to the heap section for "fixing" its lifetime. The copy mechanism is carried out in the setter method (either manually or during compilation in MRC/ARC) if 'copy' attribute is used. Directly assigning the ivar would set it but copy optimization will not happen in MRC.

Comment: There is just one more scenario where I'm facing an issue. In MRC mode, when i declare a block ptr ivar in the braces of the interface portion and then in implementation i directly assign it to a block literal, i am not getting the same issue when invoking the ptr in the main function: test->varBlock. I have made the varBlock a @public accessible var in the interface file. My point is, i didn't need to send the copy message to the varBlock ptr. And this is when i am coding in MRC mode. I haven't used self.varBlock to set the ptr properly. Rather i directly assigned it. So why no error in MRC??

Comment: @rahulbsb - Storing blocks on the stack is an *optimisation*, the compiler *can choose* to store a block on the stack, it is *not required* that it does. Under MRC the programmer needs to know about the optimisation, must assume it is always used, and insert copies as needed. Some of those copies may turn out to be redundant, but you cannot know that they will...